# Sending a web form email using Mandrill's PHP API and jQuery .ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, mandrill

I've been trying to send a simple email from a web form using Mandril. I can get an email to send using mandrill's PHP example from their api docs.

However when I try to pass in a json object through jQuery's .ajax function Mandrill is giving me this error:

```
Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in /home4/kknopper/public_html/mandrill.php on line 5
```

I'm new to working with .ajax and I feel like this could be a really simple fix.
Any help would be appreciated!

**js:**

```
//This all runs when the user submits the form

var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
var name = $("#fname").val(); // get name field value
var format = "- ";
var fname = format + name;
var message = $("#message").val(); // get message field value
message = message + "\n\n"+fname;


function log(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

var params = {
    "message": {
        "from_email": email,
        "to":[{"email":"email@gmail.com"}],
        "subject": "Web Contact Form Response",
        "text": message
    }
};

console.log(params);

var formReset = function() {
  $("#fname").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
  $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
  $("#message").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
  $("form input").attr("class","ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required");
  $("form textarea").attr("class","ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required");
  $("form button").attr("disabled","disabled");
};

$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "mandrill.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(params)
})
.done(function(response) {
  alert(response);

    console.log(response);
     // show success message
    formReset(); // reset field after successful submission
})
.fail(function(response) {
        alert('Error sending message.');
            return false; // prevent page refresh
})

.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0].status);
    alert('Your message has been sent. Thank you!');

    if (!data.success) {
      // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
        // $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
        // $scope.errorSuperhero = data.errors.superheroAlias;
    } else {
      // if successful, bind success message to message
        $scope.message = data.message;
    }
});
```

**mandrill.php:**

```
<?php
require_once 'mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill.php';
try {
  $mandrill = new Mandrill('my api key');
  $input = json_encode($_POST('params'));

  //If I pass in this message variable the email sends.
  // $message = array(
//     'text' => $input.message.text,
//     'subject' => 'Web Contact Form',
//     'from_email' => $_POST["params.message."],
//     'from_name' => 'Example Name',
//     'to' => array(
//         array(
//             'email' => 'email@gmail.com',
//             'name' => 'Recipient Name',
//             'type' => 'to'
//         )
//     )     
// );
$async = false;

$result = $mandrill->messages->send($input, $async);
print_r($result);

} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
// Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
throw $e;
}
?>
```

Comment: Check the answer. The problem on `$_POST('params')`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JSON that you are sending to the backend we can see:

```
{
    message: {
      ...
    }
}
```

But in the line #5:

```
$input = json_encode($_POST('params'));
```

You are accessing it using `params` index that actually does not exist in the post data. The right index is `message`.

EDITED:
Further than that the error is related to the way you are accessing the array $_POST. You are using parentheses to index the $_POST variable when you should use brackets []. Using parentheses the PHP tries to call the function represented by the string in $_POST which is not a string.

Comment: I tried passing that in, but I got the same error message.

Comment: Pedro I added in brackets but I get the following error instead: A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_ValidationError - Validation error: {"message":"Please enter an array"}